# There is no role in id '#' in Spatie Laravel Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream, laravel-permission

I am trying to create a Laravel project that uses Jetstream, a full-page Livewire component, and I am trying to use [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) for the permissions. I always get the error of

> Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist There is no role with id `2`.

I have three roles

```
1=Super Admin 
2=Admin 
3=User
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

User Livewire Component

```
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;

class Users extends Component
{
    public $userId;
    public $userData;

    public function addRole()
    {
        $this->userData = User::find($this->userId);
        $this->userData->assignRole(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spatie caches its data, so if you insert data directly to the database without refreshing the cache, it will not recognize the role. Try running `php artisan permission:cache-reset`. If that doesn't work, which guards do you use for these roles?

Answer (score 6):

Clear Spatie cache

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

then

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

if not work add this code to model

```
protected $guard_name = 'api';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same situation and fixed it later as follows.
change the value of 'guard_name' column in roles table and permissions table.

[image: role table image]